# MySql no output by date

Tags: mysql

[image]I dont know how the solution for this
Table1

Table2[[image]][]

the sql

```
    SELECT penjualan.tgl_penjualan, 
       SUM(total_jual) AS totaljual, 
       max(b.total_beli) AS totalbeli 
FROM penjualan 
JOIN (SELECT tgl_pembelian, sum(total_beli) AS total_beli FROM pembelian
      GROUP BY tgl_pembelian) AS b 
  ON penjualan.tgl_penjualan = b.tgl_pembelian 
GROUP BY penjualan.tgl_penjualan ORDER BY penjualan.no_penjualan DESC
```

Why **2017-07-26** no output?

the output
[output sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RkPd.png)

Comment: Are 'penjualan.tgl_penjualan' and 'pembelian.tgl_pembelian' the same datatype?

Comment: This looks as thought it should work.Can you publish the table definitions and the output from the query please.

Comment: tgl_penjualan totaljual totalbeli
2017-08-16 4404000 18051000
2017-08-14 811000 2017
2017-07-25 700000 2017

Comment: Given the data and query provided that's not the output I would expect since there are not matching records in pembelian for 2017-08-14 or 2017-07-25.

Answer (score 0):

Please try once last date `2017-07-27` instead of this `2017-07-26`.(I don't have valid reputation that's why I am commenting here.).